# Getting Color of the Screen in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

Is it possible to get the current color of the current screen on an Ubuntu 10.04 desktop?

Comment: What *part* of the screen? Using what technologies? (Or are you happen with a range from assembler to Ruby?) Seriously, this question is just completely vague -- surprisingly so given eight months on SO with 10 previous questions.

Comment: Any part of the screen. I am not sure which technology to use. My intention is to get the color of the screen, eg. at point 100x100 and use that color as a background on a Tk window that I will be using.

Comment: So you wish to get the colo(u)r value of a specific *pixel*? And using which language?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Color picker utility (color pipette) in Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003632/color-picker-utility-color-pipette-in-ubuntu)

Comment: I'm guessing that you want an application to give you an RGB value.  That's often called an "eyedropper" application. See e.g. gpick, as described at [Color picker utility (color pipette) in Ubuntu - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003632/color-picker-utility-color-pipette-in-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

I would open the background image in The Gimp (image editor. install with 'sudo apt-get install gimp') and use the dropper to select the color on the specific point. That will give you the RGB value of the color at that point

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to use an eyedropper tool such as gcolor2 which you can install using apt-get or aptitude.