# Color picker utility (color pipette) in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, color-picker

I'am looking for a color picker utility on Ubuntu/Debian.
Anything simple and easy to use.

Comment: Good question, but should be on askubuntu not SO!

Comment: You can also use [Pick](http://kryogenix.org/code/pick/) color picker for ubuntu

Comment: I literally LOL when I read 17 up-votes for someone slapping proverbial hands over what is a "valid" or "invalid' question for SO, but then there are 337+ up-votes on the answer.

Comment: `grabc` is the most simple solution. All the other solutions don't have an option to just output the color on stdout. Unfortunately this question is closed, so I can't post this as an answer.

Comment: There's a color picker in Chrome Devtools: right-click any page -> Inspect -> click any colored rectangle for a css rule that has a color/background attribute defined. See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/some-ui-and-feature-enhancements-to-the-colour-picker-tool (you can also double click a class and type eg `color:blue` by hand to get the color picker icon to show)

Comment: Here's the question on AskUbuntu: [What's a simple colour picker app for GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/q/82045/2355)

Answer (score 574, accepted):

I recommend GPick:

```
sudo apt-get install gpick
```

Applications -> Graphics -> GPick

It has many more features than gcolor2 but is still extremely simple to use: click on one of the hex swatches, move your mouse around the screen over the colours you want to pick, then press the <kbd>Space bar</kbd> to add to your swatch list.

If that doesn't work, another way is to click-and-drag from the centre of the hexagon and release your mouse over the pixel that you want to sample.  Then immediately hit <kbd>Space</kbd> to copy that color into the next swatch in rotation.

It also has a traditional colour picker (like gcolor2) in the bottom right-hand corner of the window to allow you to pick individual colours with magnification.

Comment: Unfortunately **gpick** isn't in repositories in my 11.04 (natty), but is possible download deb package from http://code.google.com/p/gpick/

Comment: Ah, sorry about that - I was using 11.10 where it seems to be in the repos... still, impressively useful piece of software - have found myself using it a lot recently for mocking up colour schemes

Comment: It's really better than gcolor2, thx.

Comment: Was trying to get hex values from my iTerm2 colour scheme so I could apply them to my Terminal app in Ubuntu. This saved me a lot of time. Thanks, @Seb!

Comment: Gimp would also do the trick, but this is WAY much lighter!

Comment: This app has a very non-intuitive UI; for example: why spacebar and not just normal click? After reading the instructions in this answer, the app instantly became more useful. But here's the kicker: **Right-click on the center hexagon to move mouse freely**.  That is: 1) Right-click on the center hexagon, 2) Move mouse freely to hover a color, 3) Press spacebar to add color to selected hexagon in the palette. Note that after adding a color, the palette will automatically move to the next color, so you can press space successively to add 6 colors in total before overwriting the first.

Comment: `gpick`  is way also too big in term of screen space. I would love to see something with the size of `ColorPix` or similar.

Comment: @rbaleksandar you can use `gpick -s`

Comment: An alternative is to use the colour picking tool in Krita.  It allows you to choose a colour anywhere on the screen (not just in the current document).  gpick's ui is almost useless!!

Comment: I personally ignore the UI and use it through a keyboard shortcut mapped to `gpick -s`, as @Yukulélé pointed out. It does exactly what it needs to do and nothing more that way.

Comment: THis is not working anymore on Ubuntu 20 and on wayland. You can `sudo apt-get install gcolor3` instead

Answer (score 114):

You can install the package `gcolor2` for this:

```
sudo apt-get install gcolor2
```

Then:

```
Applications -> Graphics -> GColor2
```

Comment: The advantage over gpick is as follows: with one click, I can copy the color into the X primary clipboard and paste it with a click on middle mouse button. With gpick, I need to use a menu, and then I only paste it in the secondary clipboard, which means that I need to use Ctrl-V (or Shift-Ctrl-V in a terminal).

Comment: Simpler and easier to use than gpick

Comment: I also find gpick extremely unintuitive. It does look powerful, but whichever brain made this works a lot different than mine. Having to "learn" a color picker seems a crazy notion. :P gcolor2 is simple and does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I would have liked to see a zoomed picker. Does this need to be activated somewhere?

Comment: just for info it seems that gcolor2 isnt in repositories anymore, and its not compatible to wayland.

Comment: But there is rescue - it seems that finaly someone made gcolor3: https://hjdskes.github.io/projects/gcolor3/

Comment: This package doesn't seem to be available in Ubuntu 18.04, but [the accepted answer here gives another way to install it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073990/gcolor2-package-missing-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: on Ubuntu 20 you probably need to install bunch of things for installing gcolor3 using flatpak.  I'm using [color-picker](https://snapcraft.io/install/color-picker/ubuntu) from snap.``sudo snap install color-picker``